# How to stitch nodes in a tour

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I want to implement [Clarke-Wright](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/champalg/tsp/tsp.html) heuristic for TSP problem. In the last phase, it requires to stitich nodes to construct a cycle. I am seeking for an efficient way to implement it in C/C++. More details and a toy example are described below:

I have n data points (so there exist n nodes in the final tour). I applied first steps of Clarke-Wright algorithm and have a nx2 matrix (each row represents an edge). I want a nx1 array with distinct nodes that represents the sequence of nodes in the final tour.

Example:
n=5

(unordered edges, for example  the first row shows the nodes 1 and 2 are adjacent in the final tour)

A:

```
 1   2

 4   3

 3   2

 1   5

 4   5
```

(final tour)
B:
1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the hub vertex is `0`. Make a vector `xor_adj` where each vertex maps to the XOR of its neighbors (you can build this incrementally while selecting edges). Find a vertex `v` that is a neighbor of the hub vertex and extract the edges with this loop.

```
int u = 0;
while (true) {
    // emit the edge u->v
    if (v == 0) break;
    int w = xor_adj[v] ^ u;
    u = v;
    v = w;
}
```

Comment: would you please trace some steps of your algorithm for the toy example in the question.